# Errors with Beautiful Soup output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage on [gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/batman-arkham-knight/) using `beautifulsoup`.  However, the result is very different than what I get from the `page source viewer`.  First off, alot of `errors` are produced.  For instance, we have

```
r = requests.get(link) 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

And yet `soup.title` gives

> `<title>404: Not Found - GameSpot</title>`.

The data I actually want to scrape does not even appear.  Is it because the webpage contains `javascript` alongside ?  If so how can I get around this ?

Comment: It is possible they block/redirect you thinking you are a bot: You might have to set you user agent.

Answer (score 1):

You're only sending a HTTP request to the server. You need to process Javascript to get the content.

A headless browser with Javascript support, like Ghost, it'd be a good choice.

```
from ghost import Ghost

ghost = Ghost()

ghost.open(link)
page, resources = ghost.evaluate('document.documentElement.innerHTML;')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

`.evaluate('document.documentElement.innerHTML')` will show the dynamically generated content, not the static you'd see taking a look at the source.

Comment: Apparently, ghost does not have the attribute open ?  I installed on the dependencies shown here http://ghostpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#examples yet ghost.open() is not available.

Comment: It has.

You need install pyqt4 first. You've got the binaries here: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

And then `pip install ghost.py`. Not only `ghost`

Answer (score 0):

Your connection error is: socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
When your first time connect to http://www.gamespot.com
you must catch cookie and use it for other pages in header of response.